# How to disable selection animations in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, selected

I currently have a custom UICollectionViewCell where I override `setSelected:`. The header file states: `The collection view may call the setters inside an animation block.` The selection is being animated, but I don't want the animation.

[image: animated selection]

I tried to disable the animation with:

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    self.label.font = font;
}];
```

As well as `+[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:]`, but the animation is still present.

My guess is that the font change is not itself animated, but it triggers a layout pass since the label is now larger. Is there a way to disable the layout of the cell?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the font does trigger a layout. Forcing an immediate layout pass, prevents any visible animation when the cell is selected/deselected. This is my custom cell `setSelected:` method:

```
 - (void) setSelected:(BOOL)selected;
 {
   [super setSelected:selected];
   self.label.font = self.selectedFont;
   [self layoutIfNeeded]; // force layout to avoid UICollectionView animation
 }
```